# How to query second 10 records order by date in varchar format in DB2

Tags: db2

assuming below table;

```
column name | type
id          | int
date        | varchar
```

When I use

```
SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY TYPE_DATE ) as ROWID,
       TO_DATE( date, 'mm\dd\yyyy' ) as TYPE_DATE,
       * 
FROM TABLE
```

I always get below error:

```
SQL0104N an expected token "*" was found following .... <select_sublist>
```

here are three questions:

1. Why can't `*` be used here?
2. Why can't this new column be used in `OVER()`
3. How can I get the set of second 10 records, order by a formatted column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, it is because you have designated additional columns, and DB2 is unable expand this `*` to a column list.  You can fix this by adding a table identifier `FROM TABLE T`, and using the exposed identifier to expand the column list `SELECT ..., T.*`

As you can see on this chart from the [Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000875.html), you can only have EITHER `*` OR expressions and `exposed-name.*`

```
>--+-*-----------------------------------------------+---------><
| .-,-------------------------------------------. |   
| V                                             | |   
'---+-expression--+-------------------------+-+-+-'   
    |             | .-AS-.                  | |       
    |             '-+----+--new-column-name-' |       
    '-exposed-name.*--------------------------'
```

For two and three, the column can't access the value of a function in the same `SELECT` clause by referring to it by its alias.  You can push it lower into a sub-select, and then use the `OVER()` function.  You can then get the rows you want by adding a `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY TYPE_DATE ) as ROWID, T1.*
FROM (
    SELECT TO_DATE( date, 'mm\dd\yyyy' ) as TYPE_DATE, T.* 
    FROM TABLE T
) T1
WHERE ROWNUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY TYPE_DATE ) BETWEEN 10 AND 20
ORDER BY TYPE_DATE
```

Comment: If we use 3 more sub select which has *, will it impact performance?

Comment: such as select T1.*, 'new columns 2'  from (  select T.*, 'new column' FROM (  select * from T ) as T1 ) as T2, will the performance very bad?

Comment: No, probably not.  The optimizer will very like (in your example) fold that down into a single select.  It depends on your actual query, though, so you should always check the path with [Visual Explain](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idm/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.datatools.visualexplain.data.doc%2Ftopics%2Ftvetop.html)